# Cant get value of scores hitTestObject

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hittest

error when adding scores. when mc1 hitTestObject line scores plus 1, and when mc2 scores did not increase

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, scoring);
function scoring(e:Event):void
{
    if (mc1.hitTestObject(line) || mc2.hitTestObject(line))
    {
        score = +1;
        myscore.text = String(score);
    }
}
```

please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not write `score = +1` to increase the score because it will give you always `1`, instead you can do like this :

```
score ++;
```

OR

```
score += 1;
```

OR

```
score = score + 1;
```

For more information take a look on [ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Operators](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/operators.html).

Hope that can help.